# How to resolve 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, build

the app already had **`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'`**.so to stay updated i changed it to 28.0.0. and i still get the **Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'**. error.

how can i solve this error permanently.
i've tried a lot of different solutions provided to similar kind of problems but didn't work.

**updated**
build.gradle down below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "man.ravi.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.adefruandta.spinningwheel:spinningwheel:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    implementation 'org.immutables:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

btw..you can `ignore the compileSdkVersion on the Top. it used to be implementationSdkVersion which resulted in a bunch of other erros..then i changed it to compileSdkVersion.

Comment: post your build.gradle please?

Comment: Try to search for "compile" word in you build.gradle files and replace it to "implementation", and also replace "testCompile" to "testImplementation"

Comment: Those aren't errors, but warnings, you can ignore them

Comment: @haresh please check out the build.gradle

Comment: @easy_breezy i did search,but couldn't find any compile.

Comment: @LucaMurra i can,but it fails to build an apk.so i have to resolve them.

Comment: also your  project  level gradle if possible?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just update Google  service  in project  level gradle.

```
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Comment: it will work for you just update  google  service  in project level gradle to latest version.

Comment: nope, that didn't work but i figured what the issue was. its Done now. let me know if i should post the answer or not.